# Math.Min for objective function

Tags: ms-solver-foundation

Given two decision variable d1,d2 that take in only number 0 and 1
if the objective function is the sum of them we can express it by

```
Term t1=d1 + d2;
 model.AddGoal("goal", GoalKind.Maximize,t1);
```

Now I wish to take the smaller of them, i.e.
Term

I want to write an objective function where

```
Math.min(d1,d2)
```

How to express the Math.min here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) class contains a substantial set of relevant mathematical operations in the form of static methods, for example [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.min%28v=vs.93%29.aspx).

You could simply write:

```
Term t1 = Model.Min(d1, d2);
```

and you are good to go :-)

Comment: Hi I got the problem
"Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.SimplexDirective cannot solve MINLP models. Remove this directive and use a directive that supports the MINLP capability."
When using Model.Min, I am using 
context.Solve(new SimplexDirective());

Comment: If you are really aiming to solve this objective function using (Mixed Integer) Linear Programming you should consider reformulating it as a _maximin_ problem. In [this](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_linearprogrammingtricks.pdf) document you can find some tricks on how to do this for the analogous _minimax_ problem. Otherwise, direct optimization of objective functions incorporating _Min_ require nonlinear methods, such as Nelder-Mead.

Comment: Hi, I guess I got the transform the formula as you said. I have some questions regarding transforming objective function here, see if you know:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482414/convert-multiplication-and-minimum-operation-for-linear-programming